# How to make an ideal cache.?

Tags: java, caching

In an application we are using an LRU(Least Recently Used) cache(Concurrent HashMap Implementation) with Max-size constrain. I'm wondered whether i could improve the performance of this cache. Following were few alternatives which i found on the net .

- Using Google Gauva pool library.(since my implementation uses LRU , I dont see any benefit from gauva library)
- If i wrap the objects as soft-references and store as values in LRU map(with out any size constrain) , can i see any benefit ? (This is not an ideal way of caching. After major gc run , all the soft references will be garbage collected).
- How about using a hybrid pool which is a combination of  LRU map + a soft reference map.(idea is when ever a object is pruned from LRU map , it is stored in a soft reference map.
  By this approach we can have more number of objects in cache. But this approach might be a time consuming one.)

Are there any other methods to improve the performance of cache?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, welcome to the club of cache implementers and improvers!

Don't use LRU. There are a lot of algorithms that are better then LRU, that are now
more then 10 years old meanwhile. As a start read these relevant resarch papers:

- [Wikipedia: LIRS Caching Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LIRS_caching_algorithm)
- [Wikipedia: Adaptive Replacement Cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_replacement_cache)

Within these papers you find also more basic papers about the idea of adaptive caching.
(e.g. 2Q, LRFU, LRU-k).

Warpping objects: It depends on what you want to achieve. Actually you have at least three additional object for a cache entry: The hashtable entry, the weakreference object, the cache entry object. With this approach you increase the memory footprint and if you
have a low efficiency, e.g. because of short expiry, you have a lot of GC trashing.

Adapt to available memory: If you want to adapt to the available memory it is better to evict entries if memory becomes lower. This way you evict entries that are used very seldom, instead of a random eviction. However, this approach affords more coding. EHCache with Auto Resource Control has implemented something like this.

The reference wrappers are a nice and easy way if you want to use more memory for the cache but avoid low heap conditions, but it is nothing high performance in terms of over all memory efficiency and access times.

Measure it! It depends heavily on the usage scenario whether you get an "performance improvement" or not. Ideally you need to know and consider the access pattern, the cached object sizes, expiry constraints and the expected parallelism. I put together a benchmark suite that you can find on GitHub [cache2k benchmarks](https://github.com/headissue/cache2k-benchmark).

However, for now, these benchmarks just focus on the replacement policy efficiency and access times. Comparison of memory overhead and possible parallelism is missing. This will be added in somehow half a year scope. The benchmark results are available on the [cache2k benchmark results](http://cache2k.org/benchmarks.html) page.

If you are generally interested in the topic and do some research in the field consider contributing to cache2k. I am especially happy about more benchmarking code, or descriptions of usage scenarios and traces of access patterns to optimize and improve the replacement algorithm.